# SetPropertyValue not recognized in powershell

Tags: powershell

My OS is windows 10 and I am using powershell to attempt to create a dsn entry
This is the command I used:

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name MyTest2 -DriverName "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" -DsnType System 
    -SetPropertyValue @("Server=MyServer", "Description=My second Test","User=MyTestUser","Password=12345", "Database=MyTestDB")
```

The dsn entry was created but I got this error:

```
-SetPropertyValue : The term '-SetPropertyValue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:5
+     -SetPropertyValue @("Server=MyServer", "Description=My se ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-SetPropertyValue:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Please advise what is wrong in my statement and if possible how to fix it?

Update:

I joined the 2 lines

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name MyTest3 -DriverName "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" -DsnType System -Platform '32-bit' -SetPropertyValue @("Server=MyServer", "Description=My second Test","User=MyTestUser","Password=12345", "Database=TestDB")
```

and I got this error:

```
Add-OdbcDsn : Invalid keyword-value pairs (Installer error code: 8).
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-OdbcDsn -Name MyTest3 -DriverName "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MyTest2 (32-bit ODBC System DSN):Root/Microsoft/...SFT_OdbcDsnTask) [Add-OdbcD 
   sn], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 0,Add-OdbcDsn

Add-OdbcDsn : Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator failed (Installer error code: 11).
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-OdbcDsn -Name MyTest3 -DriverName "SQL Serv
```

Comment: Parameters aren't automatically joined with the previous line so you need ` at the end of the previous line. [How to enter a multi-line command?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3235850)

Comment: I see..Thanks! I joined them in one line but I still got the error... See my update

Comment: I have just updated the statement with everything on 1 line

Comment: The additional error messages mean there's an unsupported value in the parameters.

Comment: Do you know which value is not supported? I hope it is not user or password...my dba set the connection to use user logon and password, not windows authentication.

Comment: @BenH: I do not think this is the issue. I removed user and password and replaced it with window authentication with a different database and it worked. I find it hard to believe that -SetPropertyValue does not take user and password. Must be something incorrect in my statement and I do not know what was wrong...

Answer (score 4):

After your update the issue is the keys username and password are not recognized for a SQL connection string.

Update them to `"Uid=MyTestUser","Pwd=12345"` and it should work.

More info can be found at [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/).

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit for me? Are you saying I need to do this in 2 steps: First create the entry with no uid and pwd, then update the newly added entry using set_odbcdsn with -SetPropertyValue again with uid and pwd?

Comment: This is the error I got:  Attempt to set the {UID or PWD} key of a DSN. These keys should not be stored in the registry for security 
reason. I can not set uid and pwd. Not sure how you did it. Please advise.